# Cannot get forward-token right using treesit node functions

Tags: navigation, tree-sitter

I'm trying to figure out how to create a forward-token function using treesit. So far I have the following.

```
(defun forward-token (&optional arg limit past-ws named)
  "Move point forward ARG tokens (backward if ARG is negative).
If ARG is omitted or nil, move point forward one word.
The return value is the new position."
  (interactive "P")
  (ignore limit past-ws named)
  (let ((arg (or arg 1))
        (count 0))
    (while (< count arg)
      (let* ((curr (treesit-node-at (point) nil named))
             (next (treesit-node-next-depth-first curr named)))
        (if next
            (goto-char (treesit-node-start next))
          (message "At last token")     ;TODO: include `count' in message
          (ding)))
      (setq count (1+ count)))))

(defun treesit-node-next-depth-first (curr &optional named)
  "Pick next of CURR in depth-first order.
If NAMED is non-nil filter on named nodes only."
  (or (treesit-node-child curr 0 named)      ;1. child (depth-first)
      (treesit-node-next-sibling curr named) ;2. sibling
      (let ((next (treesit-node-parent curr)))
        (while (and next
                    (let ((next-sibling
                           (treesit-node-next-sibling next)))
                      (when next-sibling
                        (setq next (treesit-node-parent next)))
                      (null next-sibling))))
        (when next
          (treesit-node-next-depth-first next)))))
```

But it doesn't quite work it only works for partial navigation but the it either gets stuck in a loop or in walks incorrectly backwards in some places. Need help figuring out what's wrong.

**Update**:

I instead tried

```
(defun backward-token (&optional arg tactic)
  "Move point backward ARG tokens (forward if ARG is negative).
If ARG is omitted or nil, move point backward one word.
The return value is the new position."
  (interactive "P")
  (treesit-beginning-of-thing 'token arg tactic))

(defun forward-token (&optional arg tactic)
  "Move point forward ARG tokens (backward if ARG is negative).
If ARG is omitted or nil, move point forward one word.
The return value is the new position."
  (interactive "P")
  (treesit-end-of-thing 'token arg tactic))
```

provided that the mode of interest provides a new entry `token` in `treesit-thing-settings` as for instance

```
((d (token "")
    (sexp (not "[](),[{}]"))))
```

. However this doesn't recurse into sub-node children because we are missing a `tactic` to do this. We need a variant of `nested`, say `recurse-nested` that recurses into node children.